# Question on orientation-preserving homeomorphism

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $B:=[0,1]^n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $f:B\rightarrow B$ be an orientation-preserving homeomorphism. If for any $(x_1,...x_n)$ on the boundary of $B$, $f(x_1,...x_{n-1},x_n)=(x_1,...,x_{n-1},1-x_n)$ then can we draw out a contradiction?

(Intuitively, can a cube be reversed by an orientation-preserving homeomorphism? It seems it shouldn't but I don't know its rigorous proof)

Comment: No, this is not possible. Any orientation preserving homeomorphism of a connected orientable manifold-with-boundary $M$ also preserves orientation of the boundary of $M$.

Comment: ... but your map of the boundary reverses the orientation of the boundary.

Comment: @LeeMosher - Is there any reference I can find the theorem you mentioned? I tried to find but I couldn't.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer with some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Any orientation preserving homeomorphism of a connected orientable manifold-with-boundary also preserves the orientation of the boundary of $M$.

You can find discussions of manifolds, their boundaries, and orientations thereof, in most algebraic topology textbooks, usually in the section on Poincare Duality. Sometimes the things you want to know are contained in the exercises. Often the answers require a strong knowledge of homology and cohomology, including a smattering of category theory.

For example, in Hatcher's algebraic topology, section 3.3 contains the following two exercises (both are stated over any coefficient ring; I'll simplify the statements to assume integer coefficients):

30. Show that boundary of an orientable manifold is also orientable.
31. Show that if $M$ is a compact orientable $n$-manifold, then the boundary map $H_n(M,\partial M) \to H_{n-1}(\partial M)$ [also known as the "connecting homomorphism of the long exact sequence of homology"] sends a fundamental class for $(M,\partial M)$ to a fundamental class for $\partial M$.

Exercise 31 answers your question for the compact case, because the connecting homomorphisms are natural transformations. The noncompact case can also be handled by using a somewhat different natural transformation, namely the connecting homomorphism of cohomology with compact supports.

Having said all of that, it's probably possible to piece together a more elementary argument, if you work carefully through the proof of Exercise 30.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid or misplaced question, but is there a (similar) result to sequences of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms? More precisely, if a sequence of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of an orientable manifold converges uniformly to a homeomorphism, is this limit mapping necessarily orientation-preserving again?

Comment: Sounds like a good question. You might want to ask it in a separate post. When asked as a comment to an answer to an old question, no-one will see it but the answerer (me), and perhaps also the questioner.